# How to forward dmesg live output through SSH on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, logging, ssh, dmesg

On VMWare or on bare metal, Linux display by default live dmesg content directly to stdout.

[image: ifup/ifdown]

But when I'm connected through SSH, it doesn't show up even to the command succeeds

How do I forward every dmesg log through SSH ?

`dmesg -wH`, `watch` or `tail` are not what i'm looking for. I don't want to see the whole dmesg, only the live ones and without disrupting my shell.

Comment: `/dev/tty1` is configured to be the **console**, and system messages are written to the console; that's why you see your "dmesg" messages when login in "locally"

Comment: You can always use `dmesg -W &` to run it *in background* (it's output will go to the terminal; to stop it run `fg` to get it to foreground and press `Ctrl-C` as usual, or kill the process).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @mjf, you were close.

`dmesg -W &` doesn't seems to be working since `-W` uppercase doesn't exist, but `dmesg -w &` with `-w` lowercase works perfectly.

Comment: Well, @Tangogov, on all my systems the `-W` option exists and is described in the manual page as `-W, --follow-new Wait and print only new messages.` There is also the mentioned `-w` with this description in the manual: `-w, --follow Wait for new messages. This feature is supported only on systems with a readable /dev/kmsg (since kernel 3.5.0).` Also, the `-w` first prints the circular buffer and then waits for new messages to arrive, the `-W` just waits for new messages to arrive. Just to clarify...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dmesg --follow`. This is a built-in argument in dmesg.

Answer (score 0):

To disable messages to console: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`. To read messages at a remote machine: `ssh yourname@frommachine "cat /dev/kmsg"` and to get it into a file at the remote machine while watching: `ssh yourname@frommachine "cat /dev/kmsg" | tee frommachinessyslog.log`.